# Safari on iPhone 6 being redirected for one website

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

When I try to visit [one particular webpage](http://lumenaris.com/games.html) (on my employer's site), it's being redirected to [a spam site instead](http://online-rxshop.us).  How can I fix this?

I'm using:

- iPhone 6
- AT&T cellular data (I'm not on a wi-fi network, so there's no router to check.)
- Safari

It doesn't happen:

- for other web addresses (including other pages on [the very same site](http://lumenaris.com))
- using other browsers (such as the StackExchange app)
- using a different iPhone

I've tried:

- clearing Safari's history and website data
- disabling Javascript in Safari's settings
- turning the phone off and on

Comment: Are you typing http:// or https:// before the hyperlink?

Comment: @MelvinJefferson, I just tested both options and *neither* of them was redirected.  I do so love working on intermittent problems...

Comment: Lets try doing it in a private window. If it does so on that then it could be software related.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson, it's loading correctly in both regular and private Safari now.  No idea what changed from earlier.